# I get error while downloading BERT models for summarization

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm a novice in writing neural networks. I have just started using BERT models, while running BERT for text summarization using the examples in [bert extractive summarizer](https://pypi.org/project/bert-extractive-summarizer/) I get the following error with the pretrained model getting halted at 57%.

`OSError: Couldn't reach server at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/models.huggingface.co/bert/bert-large-uncased-pytorch_model.bin' to download pretrained weights.`

How do I resolve this error.
Thanks.

Comment: The error message says it all. Check your internet connection, and try manually pinging the respective server to see whether you can actually reach it. If the connection times out after a while, I suspect that your ISP might have to do something with that.

Comment: @dennlinger Thanks for the suggestion. I shall check it manually.

Comment: @dennlinger I pinged it locally on my system, the server was responding. I could download the file too. however, when i try doing it through code, I get the above error

Comment: Have you tried removing the local copy of the model?

Comment: @dennlinger yes i did however, the error is persistent.